# How to solve this special ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE
$$
\frac{dv}{dt}=v^2+1.
$$
I do not know how to solve this ODE. I would be very thankful to get some help.

Comment: Did you learn separation of variable?

Comment: Yes, if we have $v'(t)=h(v)g(t)$.

Comment: Now $g(t) = 1$.

Comment: How to separate then? Dividing by $v^2$ does not work, or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = v^2 + 1 \implies \frac{dv}{v^2 + 1} = dt
$$
Now integrate both sides.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then we get $v(t)=\tan(t+C)$.

Comment: @Rhjg That's right.

Answer (score 3):

We separate variables to obtain $\int \frac{1}{1+v^2} dv=\int dt$. We know that $\frac{d}{dv}[\arctan(v)]=\frac{1}{1+v^2}$, so our integral just becomes

$\arctan(v)+C=t+D$. Let $D-C=C_1$ and take $\tan$ of both sides to obtain $v=\tan (t+C_1)$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{dv}{dt}=v^{2}+1\rightarrow\frac{dv}{v^2+1}=dt\rightarrow\tan^{-1}(v)=t+c
$$

Answer (score 3):

You should be knowing $\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}\ dx=\tan^{-1}(x)$,  $$\frac{dv}{dt}=v^2+1$$
Now, separate variables in given ODE as follows 
$$\frac{dv}{v^2+1}=dt$$ $$\int \frac{dv}{v^2+1}=\int dt$$ $$\tan^{-1}(v)=t+C$$